# Remove top and bottom right radius form bootstrap select

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to remove the top and bottom right border radius from a bootstrap select box to make usw of the `.input-group-addon`on the right side and to show up nicely.

I have tried this (sass):

```
select
  -webkit-appearance: none
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px
```

which works fine but unfortunately it removes the nice dropdown arrows as well which is not good.

Doing just this

```
select
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px
```

does not have any effect.

What can I do to remove the top and bottom right border but keep the arrows as well?

Comment: Are you using an addition add-on? I don't believe BS3 includes styling for select boxes.

Comment: I can't see the problem - http://jsbin.com/semoho/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @DavidNguyen of course it does!

Comment: @MoshFeu Does not work in Chrome

Comment: Screenshot from the bin on Chrome: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fO6Sb.png may can you create a snippet, maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do that? Unless I misunderstood your question, Bootstrap takes care of that anyway: http://www.bootply.com/FGxCsf8gfV

Comment: Yes exactly. But also here the borders on the right site are rounded in Chrome. I was expecting bootstrap taking care but it did not.

Comment: @DonMB could you provide a screenshot? The right side borders are rounded on the span, but they are squared on the actual select box (also viewed in Chrome).

Comment: @DonMB this is what I see when I look at the bootply link - https://www.dropbox.com/s/s7neyze471q9g5x/bootstrap-select.PNG?dl=0